# Trying to connect HDFS using python client library pyarrow but getting error FileNotFoundError. How to resolve this issue and connect to HDFS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, hdfs, pyarrow

Here I have written Python code using pyarrow library and trying to connect HDFS but getting error below:

**Code:**

```
import pyarrow
import os
import posixpath
import sys

from pyarrow.util import implements
from pyarrow.filesystem import FileSystem
import pyarrow.lib as lib

pyarrow.hdfs.connect(host='xx.xx.xx.xx', port=22, user='cloudera', kerb_ticket=None, driver='libhdfs', extra_conf=None)
```

**Error:**

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 pyarrow.hdfs.connect(host='10.40.1.8', port=22, user='cloudera', kerb_ticket=None, driver='libhdfs')
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py
>   in connect(host, port, user, kerb_ticket, driver, extra_conf)
>       213     fs = HadoopFileSystem(host=host, port=port, user=user,
>       214                           kerb_ticket=kerb_ticket, driver=driver,
>   --> 215                           extra_conf=extra_conf)
>       216     return fs
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py
>   in **init**(self, host, port, user, kerb_ticket, driver, extra_conf)
>        36                  driver='libhdfs', extra_conf=None):
>        37         if driver == 'libhdfs':
>   ---> 38             _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath()
>        39 
>        40         self._connect(host, port, user, kerb_ticket, driver, extra_conf)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py
>   in _maybe_set_hadoop_classpath()
>       138             classpath = _hadoop_classpath_glob(hadoop_bin)
>       139     else:
>   --> 140         classpath = _hadoop_classpath_glob('hadoop')
>       141 
>       142     os.environ['CLASSPATH'] = classpath.decode('utf-8')
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\hdfs.py
>   in _hadoop_classpath_glob(hadoop_bin)
>       163 
>       164     hadoop_classpath_args = (hadoop_bin, 'classpath', '--glob')
>   --> 165     return subprocess.check_output(hadoop_classpath_args)
>       166 
>       167
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in
>   check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
>       393 
>       394     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
>   --> 395                **kwargs).stdout
>       396 
>       397
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input,
>   capture_output, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
>       470         kwargs['stderr'] = PIPE
>       471 
>   --> 472     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
>       473         try:
>       474             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in
>   **init**(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines,
>   startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session,
>   pass_fds, encoding, errors, text)
>       773                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
>       774                                 errread, errwrite,
>   --> 775                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
>       776         except:
>       777             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
>
> ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in
>   _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread,
>   p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite,
>   unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)    1176
>   env,    1177                                          os.fspath(cwd)
>   if cwd is not None else None,
>   -> 1178                                          startupinfo)    1179             finally:    1180                 # Child is launched. Close the
>   parent's copy of those pipe
>
> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

How to resolve this issue and connect to HDFS?

Comment: Can you come to user@arrow.apache.org to ask?

Comment: Tried to post on user@arrow.apache.org but mail is bounced.